# NavController's push doesn't show Google Maps

Tags: html, google-maps, typescript, ionic2

I am trying to draw a map when a button is clicked. However, it doesn't seem to work when I use `NavController.push()`, but only with `NavController.setRoot()`. I don't get any errors, so I can't figure out what causes this.

This is the class that draws the map:

```
declare var google: any;


@Component({
  selector: 'page-Map',
  templateUrl: 'Map.html'
})



export class MapPage {

  public directionsService: any;
  public directionsDisplay: any;
  public directions: any;
  map: any;
  markers = [];

  constructor(private _theme: ThemeService, private shareService: ShareService, public ajaxService: AjaxService) {
    let rendererOptions = { draggable: true };
    this.directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
    let googleDiplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(rendererOptions);
    this.directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({ draggable: true });
    this.initMap();

  }

  //initialises the map
  initMap() {
    var point = { lat: 12.65, lng: 12.5683 };
    let divMap = (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('map'));
    this.map = new google.maps.Map(divMap, {
      center: point,
      zoom: 15,
      disableDefaultUI: true,
      draggable: true,
      zoomControl: true,
    });
    let locationOptions = { timeout: 30000, enableHighAccuracy: true, maximumAge: 0 };

    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
      this.map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude));
    }, (error) => { }, locationOptions);

    //create marker and set to initialised map
    var myLatLng = this.map.getCenter();
    this.directionsDisplay.setMap(this.map);
  }
}
```

This is the HTML:

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-navbar>
      <ion-title>Location</ion-title>
    </ion-navbar>
  </div>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
  <div id="map"></div>
</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try initializing the map after a platform.ready()

```
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';

constructor(public platform: Platform){
  // ...ALL YOUR CODE...
  platform.ready().then(() => {
    this.initMap();
  }); 
}
```

And be sure your map has the size it needs via css

```
#map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%; // 'auto' might work too
}
```

Comment: it still doesn't appear :(

Comment: it really doesn't throw anything at your console? Neither a warning? And what about the network requisitions on the developers console? is there something about the map beeing get?

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the problem. The reason why it didn't work was that the `id='map'` was already in use, so I changed the id to `id=map3` in the `Map.html`. So now my HTML file looks like this:

```
enter code here
```

I also changed

`let divMap = (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('map'));`
 to

`let divMap = (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('map3'));`

and the CSS:

`#map3 {
  height: 100%; 
}`

and the HTML:

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-navbar>
      <ion-title>Location</ion-title>
    </ion-navbar>
  </div>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
  <div id="map3"></div>
</ion-content>
```